# Add an onclick listener with an existing function using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an existing JavaScript function:

```
function changeColor(ID){

    try{
        initialize();
    }
    finally{
        changeDesign(ID);
    }
    
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
for(var x=0; x<2; x++){
        document.getElementById(x).onclick = "changeColor(" + x +")";
}
```

The output with the html should be:

```
<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="0" onclick="changeColor(0)>
```

Comment: `id`s should not begin with a digit.

Comment: @JonathanNaguin Its not working...If I click the tr...nothing is happening...

Comment: @FelixKling I also tried  'document.getElementById(x).onclick = changeColor(x);' but when I run the application, it performs the function...what I want is for the user to first click the tr before the function is performed.

Comment: Is that so surprising? `changeColor(x)` calls the function `changeColor` and then the return value will be assigned to `.onclick`. If I do `var foo = bar(42);`, then `bar` will be executed and the return value will be assigned to `foo`. That's how function calling works (but now worries, people seem to get confused when it's about event handlers ;)).

Comment: @pmark019: See the answer by [Felix Kling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17466480/109392). You must not include `(0)` because then you say: "Run the function and set the return value as onclick event".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assigning an event handler via the DOM API does **not** modify the actual HTML (in fact, the HTML source that the browser receives is readonly).

You have to assign a **function** to `.onclick`, not a string:

```
for(var x=0; x<2; x++){
    document.getElementById(x).onclick = changeColor;
}
```

where `changeColor` is defined as

```
function changeColor(){
    var ID = this.id; // `this` refers to element the handler is bound to

    try{
        initialize();
    }
    finally{
        changeDesign(ID);
    }

}
```

I recommend to read the [excellent articles about event handling on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Comment: Alternatively you can provide input parameter by wrapping in inline function like this: `document.getElementById(x).onclick = function(){changeColor(x)};`. This is useful if you need input parameters that is not accessible as properties on the element, only at the time of event binding.

Comment: Right, in this case you would have to use an IIFE though, to capture the value of the variable `x`: `(function(x) { document.getElementById(x).onclick = function(){changeColor(x)}; }(x));`.